# What steps are required to setup PostgreSQL and create a db in Windows?

Tags: postgresql, windows, setup

I have installed PostgreSQL 12 from https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/pginstaller-install-postgresql/. and put `\C:\...\PostgreSQL\12\bin` in the `PATH`.

In an admin powershell I execute `psql.exe -U postgres` and enter the password I chose in the installation wizard. Now I'm in a shell. I want to create a database so I run `createdb` but it seems the database is not created:

```
postgres-# \l
                                          List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |       Collate       |        Ctype        |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | German_Germany.1252 | German_Germany.1252 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | German_Germany.1252 | German_Germany.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                     |                     | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | German_Germany.1252 | German_Germany.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                     |                     | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)


postgres-# createdb demo
postgres-# absolute nonsense
postgres-# \l
                                          List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |       Collate       |        Ctype        |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | German_Germany.1252 | German_Germany.1252 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | German_Germany.1252 | German_Germany.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                     |                     | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | German_Germany.1252 | German_Germany.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                     |                     | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

I assume that my command `createdb demo` fails without error response as the intentionally wrong next command `absolute nonsense` fails as well. But I don't know how else to create a db, and moreover I'd like to know why this doesn't work and how to debug this.

Comment: [In psql, why do some commands have no effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026)

Comment: From the PostgreSQL manual: _**createdb** is a wrapper around the SQL command `CREATE DATABASE`. There is no effective difference between creating databases via this utility and via other methods for accessing the server._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `psql` client, you can only run SQL statements and psql commands (which start with a backslash).

So, to create a database, you would have to run

```
CREATE DATABASE demo;
```

The semicolon in the end is required to tell `psql` that the statement is complete.

---

The prompt you see:

```
postgres-#
```

shows that you didn't do that and `psql` is waiting for a continuation line. You see that from the `-`.

To delete the input buffer and get back to the prompt

```
postgres=#
```

simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Then you can enter the `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

---

`createdb` is *not* an SQL statement, but an executable (program) that you would call from the shell (or from `cmd.exe` on Windows).

So the alternative is *not* to start `psql`, but type

```
createdb -U postgres demo
```